# interpret diagnostics plots from classifierplots package in R

Tags: r

I have used a "adabag"(boosting + bagging) model on imbalanced dataset (6% positive), I have tried to maximized the sensitivity while keeping the accuracy above 70% and the best result I got where: ROC= 0.711 SENS=0.94 SPEC=0.21.

I have used classifierplots package in R for a diagnostic plot.
this is the plot:

[image]

I don't really understand how to interrupt the plots of positive instances per decile, prediction density and calibration. I have tried to find a comprehensive explanation with no success.

can you help me understand what the graphs mentioned above represent? I really want to improve the results.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the classiferplots package - the plots are so much better than the standard dotplot or caret featurePlot - very useful!